# ADB not responding. If you'd like to retry, then please manually kill "adb.exe"?

Tags: android, adb

I have searched for the solutions and they are complicated for me.  I am using Windows 7.

The main problem that this message appears when I run my app and then when I start my task manager:  I can not find any 'adb.exe' process running so I can not kill anything.

Please if you will suggest an answer make it detailed and imagine you are answering a beginner.

Comment: Which solutions did you find? What parts are complicated for you?

Answer (score 0):

Just open a command prompt and type adb kill-server, if adb comes back as a unrecognised command then either navigate to the tools folder that contains adb.exe or add this to your path in windows using the environmental variables panel in control panel

Comment: 1- with command prompt I have navigated to the folder that contains adb.exe and entered the command 'adb kill-server' and it returns :
* server not running * and the problem still exists 

2- with the environmental variables I saved 'D:\users\platform-tools\adb.exe' to the PATH variable and the same problem still exist  !!

Comment: What happens if in command prompt you try running adb? Try something like adb devices and see if your device is listed

Comment: that is what it returns :

adb server is out of date . killing ......
ADB server didn't  ACK
* failed to start demon * 
error : unknown host service

Comment: hmm, give your system a reboot and see if that clears the error

Comment: tried it several times but unfortunately no result 
 i will try again now 
the strange thing that the android studio was working very fine today 
and suddenly when I open my pc again today i found that problem !

Comment: worked again with no definite reason !! -- but thanks dave :))

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find `adb.exe` in Task Manager so I did the following, and it fixed the problem:

1. I closed the emulator and removed my phone.
2. I restarted Windows.
3. I connected the USB device and restarted the application.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on Windows, check your antivirus, see this question and answers:

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366416/unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server-unable-to-obtain-resu)

Answer (score -1):

Some problems occurs on Windows. Deleting the hidden `.android` folder under `C:\Users\...` seems to solve this.

Answer (score -2):

I've been having this same problem but under a Linux system (32-bit), after searching t'interweb and finding nothing that helped me I went about fixing this issue myself.

I found that if I try to execute certain binaries that are bundled with Android Studio they would not execute, infact both adb and java threw the same error:

> java/adb: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

The fix for java is to use the system jdk not the one bundled with Android Studio.
So I thought what the hell and changed the bundled adb binary.

First thing is to backup the bundled adb:

```
mv '/path/to/bundled/adb' '/path/to/bundled/adb~'
```

I then symlinked my system adb to Android Studio's sdk folder:
(your systems adb may be in a different location)

```
ln -s '/usr/bin/adb' '/path/to/bundled/adb'
```

And voila it works!
I think it may be due to the binaries being for a 64-bit CPU but I dunno, can anyone confirm this??

Comment: Does the down voter care to commemt on what exactly is wrong with this answer?? it is perfectly acceptable, its informative and more to the point it has fixed my problem that was the same as the OP's!!!! I moved away from Stack Exchange because i found the community to be quite tactile in there bully methods, people see a low rep and seem to think lets make it worse for them, quite frankly its disgraceful!!!!!!!