# Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

I am running Android Studio on Windows 10 64 bit. I upgraded to the latest build and SDK the morning of 5/20, and since then I get the above error when opening Android Studio. I also get the 'Unable to obtain result of 'adb version' in the event log. If I launch the application (which worked fine before the update) the 'Select Deployment Target' window appears, showing 'Initializing ADB' with a loading graphic for a few seconds, which then results in a 'Nothing to show' message. Previously I had 4 different emulators set up, and an active device connect via USB. Now ... nothing.

Creating a new emulator has no effect - I go through the steps and still see the 'Nothing to show' message.

I have tried the following:

- Reverting to older platform tools
- Removing and re-installing the latest platform tools
- Removing and re-installing Android Studio completely
- Installed Genymotion to try emulate through that (I can create and start the emulator in Genymotion, it makes no different to the above issue in AS)
- killed adb.exe through Task Manager, then ran adb tcpip 5555 through the terminal, the output was:

  - daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
  - daemon started successfully *
    restarting in TCP mode port: 5555

Which was encouraging, but the same issue described above persists (even after a restart of AS).

Switch to USB mode and back to TCPIP through adb in the terminal, no luck.

- Migrated the entire project to Eclipse until I ran into support issues with Google Play Services (so I'm going to have to stick to AS, but I am getting desperate here)

Anyone that can assist - I would greatly appreciate it.

**UPDATE - 5/23**

I did a search for adb.log and found it in a temp folder on a completely different drive to the one that contains AS or my project files. Closed everything down, killed adb.exe through the task manager and deleted the file. Upon relaunching AS I received the following message:

[screenshot of message](http://screencast.com/t/93GMaSjnR)

I could start/kill ADB through the terminal. adb devices resulted in an empty list. My idea.log file is filled with entries as from the date my trouble started. Restarting AS again resulted in the usual 'Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'' message.

Here is the last entry in my idea.log file:

> 2016-05-23 10:13:19,081 [ 824808]   INFO - tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService - Initializing adb using: E:\Users\JakeSabre\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe, client support = false 
>   2016-05-23 10:13:24,082 [ 829809]   WARN -            #com.android.ddmlib - Unable to obtain result of 'adb version' 
>   2016-05-23 10:13:24,083 [ 829810]   INFO - ditor.DeployTargetPickerDialog - Unable to obtain debug bridge 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'

```
at com.android.tools.idea.ddms.adb.AdbService$1.run(AdbService.java:236)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:366)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)
```

The really weird part is that I actually managed to get something working yesterday - but I don't know how. I started AS and received the same error, but then started Eclipse (Mars 2) and launched the Android Device Manager through Eclipse. As soon as I did I could launch my app through the AS emulator! I closed it all down and tried again, just to be sure and it worked again.

This morning I tried the same trick, but was told my SDK is missing. I checked and platform-tools was indeed missing (not sure why). So I installed it again, got the usual error, and now my trick with Eclipse is no longer working. I feel like I am in the Twilight Zone here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably should have done this as part of my initial troubleshooting, but I ended up disabling Windows Firewall and my anti-virus (Trend Micro). The firewall did nothing, but disabling Trend Micro completely solved the issue....

Somehow, for some reason, Trend Micro decided to start not liking the daemon being created by ADB. 4 days of tears and frustration over such a small thing. Hopefully this helps someone else one day avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is very simple. Open **'Command Prompt' as 'Administrator'**, run adb kill-server, then adb start-server. It worked for me.

Comment: As per OP: "I could start/kill ADB through the terminal. adb devices resulted in an empty list. "

Comment: Luckily, I could `adb start-server` (kill didn't work; server wasn't running) and when I restarted AS 2.3.3 all was well with my connected device showing  in Android Monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Geez, I can't it's the TrendMicro antivirus !!  ... many Thanks !

This also works for me on my 64bit Win 10, took me a day to reinstall AS and ADK and trying to figure out why ...  adb kill-server, then try disable/enable Antivirus and you'll see the difference.

For finer-grain of control, add the bin\studio64.exe of AS into the Exception List of Trendmicro Antivirus and it'll bring up adb just fine.

Comment: Glad it worked for you - one of the most frustrating issues I've ever dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

I got this fix by following this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38447003/5521389

going into GenyMotion settings -> ADB tab,
instead of Use Genymotion Android tools (default), I chose Use custom Android SDK Tools and then browsed to my installed SDK.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've provided, I'm not sure that what I'm about to type applies to your situation.  But since no one else has answered, you might want to consider it.

I had a very strange situation in which I kept getting the 'Nothing to show' message even though I had defined multiple emulated types of Android equipment, and also had a physical Android device.

I tried all sorts of things to solve the problem without success.  Then I eventually tracked down an **adb.log** file that had been created in a directory **outside** any of the usual directory trees managed by the Android tools; a directory that is usually used for temporary storage.  The access permissions on the file had somehow been changed so that one of the programs involved in debugging, could no longer access the file, and so failed to start properly.  Removing the file solved the problem.  The next time I attempted to begin debugging, everything worked as it should.

Although I was working with Linux, if the Android tools work in a similar manner with Microsoft Windows, the file might be in a directory tree identified by an environment variable, either *TMP* or *TEMP*.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Please see update in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your platform tools from the SDK manager and restart your editor

Answer (score 0):

In the Task Manager, delete adb.exe

In terminal, run command `adb start-server`