# Solving "adb server version doesn't match this client" error

Tags: android, adb, appium

I'm running my Appium script with Python instead of `py.test` because `py.test` does not play nicely with variables I want to get from a text file. When I run my script with Python everything works except that my first method always has an error.

Does anyone know how to fix the following error?

```
adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (36)
adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
```

Comment: can you paste rest of the error logs

Comment: http://pro.sr1.me/post/android-sdk-download-links, i use this to downgrade platform-tools

Comment: This was caused in my case by running Visual Studio with an Android Xamarin project on the same machine as Android Studio - each IDE had a different adb server version running. I closed Visual Studio and the error went away.

Answer (score 177):

In my case the solution was this on an Ubuntu based OS:

```
adb kill-server
sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
adb start-server
```

kudos: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38166059/3765109

Comment: I used symlink instead of copy to keep the file up to date.
```sudo ln -s ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb```

Comment: If `/usr/bin/adb` is not permitted, you can use `/usr/local/bin/adb` instead.

Answer (score 172):

I fixed this by doing the following:

1. going into GenyMotion settings -> ADB tab,
2. instead of **Use Genymotion Android tools (default)**, I chose **Use custom Android SDK Tools** and then browsed to my installed SDK.

Comment: Is there anyway to update android sdk adb?

Comment: Sorry, have not checked this at all. I was using Appium and not GenyMotion.

Comment: Settings is available separately inside the Genymotion application and not inside the android studio.

Comment: Android Studio Uses this Path: /Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk ...... Homebrew Uses this Path: /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/<version> where in my case <version> was 24.4.1_1

Comment: From Genymotion 2.6 onwards, if you want to install google apps package (required from play services) the SDK path option in the settings of genymotion must be "Use Genymotion Android tools (default)". When i do so i got this error in adb start-server: "adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (36); killing...".

Answer (score 62):

One possible reason for the occurrence of this error is due to the difference in **adb versions** in the development machine and the connected connected device/emulator being used for debugging.

So resolution is:

1. Firstly disconnect device/emulator.
2. Run on terminal/command prompt following commands:

   ```
   adb kill-server
   adb start-server
   ```

This will start the adb successfully. Now you can connect device.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah I'm already doing that cause I though that might be the problem. I have in my bash script before I run my python script. I believe I know what the problem is, not sure how to fix it. thank you though

Comment: Changing the Genymotion SDK path and restarting the adb server worked for me. Just in case someone changes the path and nothing happens

Answer (score 40):

It seems there are 2 adb version in your system. Please find them out and keep the adb in your **Android SDK** folder only, delete all others folders that including adb file.
You can find out which adb you are using from Application Monitor:

[image]

It might be a problem if the adb is not the one in you Android SDK folder.

In my case, I found I was running adb from here:

> /Library/Application Support/RSupport/Mobizen2

after deleting the Mobizen2 folder, then all adb commands work fine.

Comment: I had installed ["TC Games"](http://www.sigma-rt.com/en/tcgames/) and it included its own adb, removed it and all worked well again.

Answer (score 34):

Exactly same problem. Tried kill and start but what this worked for me:

```
adb reconnect
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Actually this worked. I am not using Genymotion and I have only one ADB installed (I even uninstalled the previous one and did everything again).

Comment: This is a temporary fix; doesn't resolve the underlying issue of having multiple versions of adb on your system

Answer (score 28):

For anyone still having this issue ( on windows ):

1. Open task manager
2. Go to processes and select the ADB.EXE
3. Right-click on it and check the properties
4. Most likely you will see a different path from where the adb.exe is running ( either HTC manager, Genymotion, etc )
5. Kill the process
6. Run ADB.exe from your android studio path ( in my case: C:\Users\%user%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools )

This solved the problem in my case.

Comment: Intel XDK runs its own version of the abd and this caused the error when I went to use Android Studio.

Comment: OK, I had the same problem and your tip helped! Thanks a lot!
It was caused by Splashtop Wired XDisplay... I had to close that program

Comment: HTC Sync (had used old phone for development... stop using phone and legacy adb still being used). Thank you!!!

Comment: I have Mobile Assistant appliation run before the adb

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 13):

On Windows, just check in the windows task manager if there are any other adb processes running.

Or run `adb kill-server`

If yes, just kill it & then perform the `adb start-server` command.

I hope, it should solve the problem.

Comment: This worked for me.   Not sure where the other ADB server comes/came from but it's not expected so it's not needed.  Ty.

Answer (score 12):

Most likely you have several adb version on your computer. You start adb server using one version and then trying to connect to this server using another version.
For example - Genymotion has it's own adb and if you start Genymotion emulator and then try to use adb from Android SDK most likely you will have such error (the latest Genymotion which is 2.7.2 has adb version 1.0.32 while the latest Android SDK has adb version 1.0.36).

Comment: What do I do in such a case if I still want to use Genymotion? Donwgrade my adb version?

Comment: I've just verified that this is my case. I'm using platform-tools 1.0.36, but Genymotion 2.6 uses adb 32. When I run a Genymotion emulator and try to run the app, no devices are detected. But if I close the emulator and then run the app, adb detects all my other devices. So what I did was starting Genymotion emulator from Android Studio and then, quickly, run the project before the emulator is entirely started. Then all my devices appear on the list and when the emulator is entirely started, it also appears on the list.

Comment: Well, I had the same issue and ended up with replacing Genymotion version of adb with up to date version from Android SDK. I'm not sure that this is the best solution but it works.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Copy adb.exe from Android SDK (it should be in platform-tools folder) to Genymotion (should be in tools folder). So for example if Android SDK is installed in C:\android-sdk and Genymotion in c:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\ you need to copy the file from c:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe to c:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools\adb.exe (make backup copy... just in case)

Comment: Uninstalling the extra adb version solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: You can also change the SDK tools path in genymotion settings. Genymotion uses its own SDK tools by default. Just point genymotion to your SDK folder. Turn off the emulator, go to Genymotion Settings, then ADB tab and select Use Custom Android SDK tools and provide a path.

Answer (score 8):

For those of you that have HTC Sync installed, uninstalling the application fixed this problem for me.

Comment: or just stop its service from task manager.

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks, very annoying "fix"

Answer (score 7):

For me it was happening because I had android tools installed in two places:
1. The location where I manually downloaded it from google
2. Automatic download by Android studio

What I was able to do was completely delete the folder in #1 and point my bash profile and all other references to the location where Android studio installed it for me: /Users/my_user_name/Library/Android/sdk

This solved it.

Comment: This is what happened to me also. When I installed Xamarin for something iOS related, it also installed it's own version of android sdk. I deleted the Xamarin android sdk folder at `/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xamarin`

Answer (score 4):

1. adb kill-server
2. **close any PC side application you are using for managing the android phone**, e.g. 360mobile(360手机助手). If necessary, you may kill such progress in task manager in case they run in background.
3. adb start-server and it should be solved

Comment: If it weren't for you, I don't know how much longer I'd be stuck here. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem since updated platfrom-tool to version 24 
and not sure for root cause...(current adb version is 1.0.36)

Also try `adb kill-server` and `adb start-server` but problem still happened

but when I downgrade adb version to 1.0.32 everything work will

Comment: @canyo how to downgrade adb to 1.0.32?

Comment: @Zamyesterday There are many way I think, but fast way is download from goolge [link](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/<sdk_name>) and seconde compile from AOSP

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. `adb kill-server`
2. Close all `chrome://inspect/#devices` windows/tabs
3. `adb start-server`
4. `adb devices`

Answer (score 1):

**Mainly you need to delete duplicate adb.exe file. You can use [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to Find.**

**keep the platform-tools adb.exe**

**and add the platform-tools directory to your Environment Path Variable.**

I am using Memu Emulator.

So, I have taken these steps:

Go to Memu Installation Directory: (In My Case D:\Program Files\Microvirt\MEmu)

And then Delete the adb.exe file.

It should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue for me was caused by having apowermirror running at the same time, from what I can tell any software that could use a different version of adb could cause these issues as others mention in this thread this can include Genymotion or from other threads unreal studio was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio then give it a try:

Remove and path variable of adb from system variable/user variable.
Then go to terminal of android studio and then type there command adb start-service.

I tried this and it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently had this issue too and after none of the answers on here worked I realised that the APK I was testing against would have been built against the latest sdk.

So I went into the Appium settings and changed the platform version to the latest version and this resolved the issue for me.