# ADB server version (39) doesn't match this client (36)

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm currently experiencing a few issues using ADB with Debian Stretch. Whenever I issue an ADB command, I get the following message:

```
$ adb root
adb server version (39) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
```

Normally this doesn't cause any issues other than a 2 second delay while the ADB server restarts, but when I'm using `adb shell` the connection will occasionally drop, which is annoying. Note that this is different to other questions [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214012/appium-adb-server-version-31-doesnt-match-this-client-36) as **the server version is greater than the client version**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem was caused by me having ADB installed twice on my machine. Once in my home directory (used by Android Studio), and again in `/usr/bin/adb` as I had the `android-sdk` package installed from aptitude. As Debian tends to be a bit slow with package updates,  `adb` from the command line was calling the older version at `/usr/bin/adb` rather than the newer version in my home folder. This issue was solved by running:

```
sudo apt-get remove adb
```