# Android Emulator shows a Black Screen on Ubuntu Android Studio AVD

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-virtual-device, virtual-device-manager

I just installed Android Studio and created my first few Virtual Devices based on

- Nexus 6 API 27
- Pixel 3 API 27
- Pixel 4a API 30
- Pixel 5 API 30
- Pixel 5 API 28
- Pixel 5 API 27
- Pixel 5 API 26
- Pixel 5 API 25

However, starting the virtual device only shows a black window, as shown here:

[image]

Some time later, nothing changes and this window appear showing a timed out message:

> Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

[image]

Tried the following but does not help:

1. Switching the virtual Device's `Graphics` from `Automatic` to `Software - GLES 2.0`
2. Adding this line to the bottom ~/.bashrc`

   ```
   export ANDROID_EMULATOR_USE_SYSTEM_LIBS=1
   ```
3. Fixed some client error by [creating this symlink for `adb`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40991118/3023615)

   ```
   adb kill-server
   #sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
   sudo ln -s ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb
   sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb
   adb start-server
   ```

Is there a fix for this? Thanks!

---

My system is running:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 4
- AMD Ryzen 5950X, 128 GB DDR, RTX 2070S
- Nvidia drivers 460.91.03
- `adb` Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41 Version 31.0.3-7562133

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm facing the same issue on 2020.3.1 Arctic Fox.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use another prescription of emulator.
Or sometimes you need to change the version of android for emulator

Comment: This issue is more pervasive than simply "you need to try another emulator". There are widespread reports of those on Nvidia based hardware having issues with AVD being unable to launch machines on Windows and Linux. Changing hardware vs software settings does not help. Disabling ADB integration does not help. Ensuring other virtual machines such as VMWare, Docker, K8s etc are not running / not present sometimes helps, but not always.