# adb server always restarts: adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41)

Tags: adb, macos-ventura

I can't debug the application to the emulator because adb is unstable as shown in the log below, I tried to do the adb device command three times but the results are different, how do I fix it?

> $ adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
>
> emulator-5554   device

> $ adb devices
>
> adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
>
> daemon started successfully
>
> List of devices attached
>
> emulator-5554   offline

> $  adb devices
>
> List of devices attached
>
> emulator-5554   device

Comment: You have two different adb versions installed and they are used alternating killing the other version. Uninstall the older adb installation and your problems are gone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214012/solving-adb-server-version-doesnt-match-this-client-error

Comment: @Robert I've used one adb but it's still an error.

Comment: No t is not an error. Adb starts itself as server and there can only be one server be active at a time. If you are mixing up different adb versions then each version tries to start itself  as server and kills the other. So remember one version and adb becomes stable.

Comment: @Robert but now only one is installed but still has an error.