# ADB not working from Android Studio after installing Xamarin

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-studio, xamarin, adb

Android Studio (Windows 7) is giving me the "Unable to create debug bridge" error, as this person describes:

[Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366416/unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server-unable-to-obtain-resu)

I have tried pretty much every solution I've found and then realized that I just recently installed Xamarin for Visual Studio 2015 as well, and I'm thinking that has screwed up Android Studio.  adb works fine from the command line.  A Google search didn't turn up any relevant results for this issue but I'm hoping someone can at least confirm that these IDEs don't play nicely together, and ideally even present a solution.  I can do my installation from the command line but of course that's a pain compared to just clicking a button in the IDE, not to mention the inconvenience of using the command line to view logcat.

Comment: Have you made sure that your Android Studio has a correct SDK path in it's options?

Comment: Yes, the SDK path is present and looks to have everything it should, such as the platform-tools directory with adb.exe in it.

Comment: I just attempted to attach the debugger to a device.  It said to kill adb and try again so I did that, and then it came up with the device (though no apps).  So I tried running the app and it worked, so at least for now it appears to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

When you installed Xamarin, did you see if another SDK was installed in a different location in your computer? Because this happened to me. I had Android Studio installed then I installed VS 2015 with Xamarin but I didn't realize that the option to install android SDK (with adb and etc) was enabled. After realizing that, I changed Xamarin configs to point to my older SDK folder (the one used by Android Studio as well), then everything worked.

Comment: Thanks, that was probably it.  It didn't occur to me when installing that it would interfere with Android Studio.  If it breaks again, I think I'll uninstall Xamarin, get Android Studio working again, and then reinstall Xamarin like you suggest.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if it works. Have a nice day!