# Android Studio: Initializing ADB Nothing to show and adb failed to start daemon

Tags: android, adb

I use Windows10 and Android Studio 2.3.3

I use Android Studio to deploy my application when "Select Deployment Target" there is no device 
can not see any virtual device in "Select Deployment Target"

I met some problem in android development
After "Select Deployment Target" refresh, the Device item still have a blank.
I can't start my android virtual device
and I also got 
adb devices doesn't show my device 
Initializing ADB Nothing to show
adb failed to start daemon
I kill adb.exe and restart and still can not see my device in "Select Deployment Target"

I see this

[Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: Unable to obtain result of 'adb version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366416/unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server-unable-to-obtain-resu)

[Eclipse error "ADB server didn't ACK, failed to start daemon"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703550/eclipse-error-adb-server-didnt-ack-failed-to-start-daemon)

[Appium: adb server version (31) doesn't match this client (36)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214012/appium-adb-server-version-31-doesnt-match-this-client-36/38447003#38447003)

I try to restart my computer, restart adb.exe but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

If adb nodaemon server or adb reboot doesn't work
You need to check your SDK and AVD PATH 
make sure your Android tools PATH is correct 
if not
you may re-install you SDK or AVD
if still not work you may re-install your android studio

Comment: thank you, I uninstall my android studio and fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all solutions. The only and easiest thing it worked, it was deleting Android Studio and reinstalling it.