# Infinity loading devices in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, adb

[I saw this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSGgD.png), when open Android Studio few minutes ago (I haven't done anything specific before) - studio infinity trying load device

Please, tell me, how I can solve this problem? If you need some data, I`m ready to take it.

**Edit: I tried invalidate cahes and restart ide, it isn`t worked**

**Edit2: I tried start emulator and get [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkUjr.png)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved [this question]. I just open terminal in sdk-directory, write "adb start-server" and delete all adb.exe in task manager.
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37366416/unable-to-create-debug-bridge-unable-to-start-adb-server-unable-to-obtain-resu)